# Is it a bad practice to open a new context or send one as a parameter into sub-methods?

Tags: entity-framework

A colleague asked for my opinion regarding the following setup. It's based on a declaration of a context in a method and then providing it into the called submethods. Schematically, it looks like so.

```
public void SuperMethod()
{
  using(Context context = new Context())
  {
    ...
    SetMethod(context, ...);
    ...
    GetMethodDuo(context, ...);
    ...
  }
}

public void SetMethod(Context context, ...) { ... }

public Some GetMethod(Context context, ...) { ... }
```

I advised him against it, motivating my answer by the idea of opening/closing access to the database as near the actual operations as possible. But now that I think about it, I'm uncertain if that was the best advice in any circumstances.

**Question 1: Was the suggestion of mine correct in a general case or should I consider altering it?**

I also noticed that the super-method calling the sub-methods used the context itself. My suggestion was to move the part that talked to the database in a new sub-method, hence freeing the super-method from any references to the context. I felt that it made sense to make the super-method a controller, while performing all the database related operations in the workers.

**Question 2: Does it make sense to have a controlling method that calls a (possibly large) number of sub-methods carrying the actual work?**

Please note that both questions are related to the usage of the context while working with Entity Framework and not a general class structure.

Comment: the DbContext is meant as a Unit of Work context, so there should be only small operations done within a single context. this has a few reasons, mainly: -the creating/disposing of a context is a very cheap operation (at least after initializing the first one), what takes time is computing the query+materializing the results, which will take place anyway. -when you keep the context open, you won't know which values are already in the context, which will ultimately lead to faulty/inefficient behavior. -contexts with a lot of data will perform very poorly and are hard to maintain.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I've read your contribution but it seems to me that there's a more appropriate way to provide it. You posted it as a comment but it appears to me that it's an actual reply (not saying it is or isn't the correct answer, yet). Please remove the comment and post the contents of it as a reply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMO, the context should be opened and disposed with every unit of work (so for example, within a simple function) - which doesn't mean you shouldn't pass your context to underlying functions. This can be exactly what you want, especially considering connection pooling and context entry lifetime.

This has a few pretty simple reasons:

1. It's pretty cheap to open a new context, it will take almost no time relatively to the main performance issues in EF like materializing values (*DataSet* to *object* and vice versa) and creating the queries - and those two have to be done with an already open context as well.
2. One main reason against opening and disposing a context every time is the opening/disposing of connections (some DBMS, I know particularly of SQL CE, have incredible problems with the creation of connections to certain databases - and EF **will** create a new connection based on the provided connection string whenever it needs one). However, you can easily surpass this, by keeping a connection open (or letting it timeout isn't too bad most of the time either) and pass it to your context upon creating, using the *DbContext(Connection, bool)* overload with *ContextOwnsConnection=false*.
3. When you keep the context open over the whole lifetime, you can't possibly know which objects are already in the change tracker, materialized or there in another form, and which aren't. For me, this was a problem when rewriting the BL of my project. I tried to modify an object, which I added earlier. It was in the context (unchanged) but not in the change tracker, I couldn't set its state, because it wasn't in the change tracker. And I couldn't attach it again, because it was already in the context. This kind of behavior will be pretty hard to control.
4. Another form of this is as follows. Whenever a new object enters the context, EF will try to set the navigation properties of these regarding the other objects in the context. This is called relationship fixup and is one of the main reasons *Include()* is working so well. This means that most of the time, you'll have a huge object tree in your context. Then, upon adding/deleting it (or whatever else operation) EF will try to carry out this to the whole tree (well... sometimes ;) ), which can cause a lot of trouble, especially when trying to add a new entry with FK to already existing items.
5. A database context is, like already mentioned, basically an object tree, which can be, depending on its lifetime, gigantic. And here, EF has to do a few things, like... Checking if an item is already there, because of obvious reasons... In best case complexity O(n*log(n)+m), where m is the number of object types and n the number of objects of this type in the context. ...Checking if an object has been modified since retrieval - well, you can imagine, since EF has to do this for **every single object** in **every single call**, this can slow things down pretty far.
6. A bit corresponding to the last issue. What do you really want, when calling *SaveChanges()*? Most likely, you want to be able to tell: "*ok, these are the actions I did, so EF should now issue these and these calls to the db*", right? Well... But, since EF has been tracking the entities, and maybe you modified some values, or another thread did something there and there... How can you be sure, these are the only things *SaveChanges()* will do? How can you be sure that over the whole lifetime of the context, there's nothing fishy in your database then (which will cancel the transaction, which can be pretty big)?

But yeah, of course, there are a few issues, where you need to keep the context open (well, you don't need to - you could just pass it). For me, this was mostly in a few cases where FK correction was hard to maintain (but still within one function, while sometimes within one function I just had to dispose and re-create the context for the sake of simplicity) and whenever you call sub-functions from multiple places in your code - I had the issue that I had a context open within a calling function, which called another function, which still needed the context. Usually, that's not a problem but my connection handling is kind of... advanced. That led to performance loss, I dealt with this by passing the already open context through an optional additional context parameter to the sub-function - just like what you already mentioned, however it shouldn't really be necessary.

For additional reference, here are some links that might be helpful in this regard. One's straight from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx) and the other from [a blog](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/).

Comment: This was a one kick-rectum reply. I took the liberty to remove some grammar errors and the (in my view totally unnecessary) humbleness. This is definitely +1 both for the size and for the thoroughness. In fact, I'll even consider doing something that I **very** rarely do - I'll **consider** assigning you a bounty. If I won't do that, it's definitely not because your reply doesn't deserve it. It's because I'm a reputation bitch and a skinto, hehehe.

Comment: Creating a large in memory object tree could be a real problem, I have had this particular problem too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628878/profiling-shows-slow-performance-when-explicitly-loading-related-entities

Answer (score 1):

As @DevilSuichiro mentioned the `DbContext` is meant as a Unit of Work container. By default `DbContext` stores all loaded objects in the memory and track their changes. When the `SaveChanges` method is called all changes are sent to a DB in the single transaction.

So if your `SuperMethod` handles some kind of a logical unit of work (e.g. a HTTP request in a web application) I would instantiate the context only once and pass it as a parameter to submethods.

Regarding your second question - if you instantiate the context only once, it's IMO better to have more methods that are simple, easier to maintain and have meaningful names. If you want to create a new instance of the context in every submethod, it depends on what "possibly large" number means :-)

Comment: By *possibly large* I mean, obviously, that there's a possibility of the number to be large. How is that unclear? Du'h... (Just kidding, just kidding - I understand your point perfectly.) However, I sense that while you agree with @devilsuichiro on the definition of *single unit of work*, you're more into creating the context once and then pass it around, wheras he suggest the opposite design of recreating it at every operation. Am I misunderstanding any of you, please?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'm more into creating the context once and use it across my code. My opinion might be biased by the fact I am working primarily on web projects, where the unit of work is clearly limited by the single HTTP request and the amount of data, we are dealing with, isn't that big (thousands of objects not millions). But unless you see any performance problems, I think it is cleaner solution.

Comment: Exactly right. In addition if you want to use a transaction you are almost forced to use a single context, conn and tran and pass those around.

Comment: @usr In our case, we have quite a large data amounts being processed within each context (different entities in each method, basically) but the output consists only of a small portion of it. I still lean towards recreating the context for each operation but I'll make sure to notify my colleague that I wasn't 100% spot on. As a follow-up question - is there any direct negative consequence to using the approach of recreation?

Comment: recreating the context is IMO better in almost every situation, simply because of EFs need to track the changes of any attached object. this will make almost any operation take longer, SaveChanges will have different side effects (because of fixup mostly), your object graph will become unreliable... well, I don't say it's necessarily a BAD approach - I tried it as well - but it just takes almost all of your control regarding relationships and transaction scope, instead of just cleanly instantiating a new context (you can even use an existing connection!)

Comment: @KonradViltersten no direct negative consequence, you can even reuse a conn+tran pair in a new context. I would advise you to look into transactions, though, because partial writes in case auf mid-way failures cause a lot of problems and work.